# How do I retrieve the rank of the names from a file and then output the stuff into my print statement?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, input, names

I need to open up a file that contains the 1000 most common boy names and how many people have their names. The file is sorted from the greatest used names to the least used names. I have to allow the user to input a name and the program should find the name (regardless of user's input letter case - i.e. upper or lower case) in the dictionary and print out the rank and the number of names. If the name isn’t a key in the dictionary, then the program should indicate this. The program continues until "-1" is entered and should say **Exiting program**. when this happens.

Example if the user enters “noah”:

Enter a name (-1 to exit): noah
Noah is ranked 2 in popularity among boys with 18739 namings.
Noah is ranked 692 in popularity among girls with 415 namings.

Enter a name (-1 to exit):

My code so far:

```
dict1 = {}
boy_names = open('boynames.txt')
for line in boy_names:
    key, value = line.split()

    dict1[key] = value
input = input('Enter a name (-1 to exit):')
grammar = input.lower().capitalize()

for i, (val, key) in enumerate(dict1.items()):
```

I am not sure what to do after this.

Comment: what does the file with the names lloook like?  The format

Comment: You can tackle the "rank" problem by storing e.g. enumerating the lines as your parse them, storing the name + rank tuple in your dictionary. Then use `name in dict1` to check for existence, and you are basically all set.

Comment: Here is some text from the file:
Liam 20272\n Noah 18739\n Oliver 14616\n Elijah 12708\n 
It is basically the name and then the number of people with that name then it is a newline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use a `while` loop to do this.

```
dict1 = {}
boy_names = open('boynames.txt')
for line in boy_names:
    key, value = line.split()

    dict1[key.lower().capitalize()] = value

# as for the while loop.
answer = input('Enter a name (-1 to exit):').lower().capitalize()

while answer != "-1":
   rank = list(dict.keys()).index(answer) + 1
   print(f"{answer} appears {dict1[answer]} times and is rank {rank}.")
   answer = input('Enter a name (-1 to exit):').lower().capitalize()

print("Exiting program.")
```

Comment: Above assumes you're parsing the file correctly. That's hard to know for sure without some file text.

Comment: Liam 20272\n
Noah 18739\n
Oliver 14616\n
Elijah 12708\n

Comment: It is basically the name and then the number of people with that name then it is a newline.

Comment: If the above is raising errors, let me know what error type.

Comment: How do I get the position of the input in the file? For example, if the input is Liam, how do I get the position of the input in the dictionary and get the rank?

Comment: The above program does not work cause the ```dict[answer]``` does not work.

Comment: Look like there was a typo. It should probably be `dict1[answer]`. Also, the rank need the `...index(answer) + 1` or it will be off.

Comment: I got the number of people who use that name by using ```dict1.get(answer)```
Now, I need to figure out a way to display the rank at which it stands at. For example, in the file, Liam is the most used name so it ranks 1 in the file. How do I get it to display the rank?